# Баг в анимации CSS

Tags: javascript, css, анимация, css-animation

Почему когда я нажимаю на `скрыть`, дожидаюсь окончания анимации, и нажимая на `показать`, анимация появления происходит не плавно? А вот если сначала нажать на `показать`, анимация выполнится плавно.

```js
  window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var block = document.querySelector("#block");
    var overlay = document.querySelector(".overlay");
    
    document.querySelector(".hide").addEventListener("click", function() {
      overlay.style.display = "block";
      overlay.className = "overlay animation--slide-up";

      setTimeout(function() {
        block.className = "animation--scale-hide";
      }, 1000);
    }, false);
    document.querySelector(".show").addEventListener("click", function() {
      overlay.className = "overlay";
      block.className = "scale-hidden animation--scale-show";
    }, false);
  }, false);
```

```css
  #block {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: green;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  }
   
  #block .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://zaytcev.com/koval/wtalfiym/test.css" type="text/css">

<div id="block">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>

<br />

<button class="hide">скрыть</button>
<button class="show">показать</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверное вы забыли добавить таймер на анимацию "Показа".

HTML без изменений

Анимацию появления добавите какую вам угодно(я сделал пример с *плавной*)

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var block = document.querySelector("#block");
    var overlay = document.querySelector(".overlay");
    
    document.querySelector(".hide").addEventListener("click", function() {
      overlay.style.display = "block";
      overlay.className = "overlay animation--slide-up";

      setTimeout(function() {
        block.className = "animation--scale-hide";
      }, 1000);
    }, false);
    document.querySelector(".show").addEventListener("click", function() {
      block.style.display = "overlay";
      block.className = "overlay animation--slide-up";
      
      setTimeout(function() {
        overlay.className = "scale-hidden animation--scale-show";
      }, 1000);
    }, false);
  }, false);
```

```css
#block {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
  max-height: 50px; /* пришлось добавить чтобы полоса не *улетала* */
    background: green;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  }
   
  #block .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://zaytcev.com/koval/wtalfiym/test.css" type="text/css">

<div id="block">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>

<br />

<button class="hide">скрыть</button>
<button class="show">показать</button>
```

Comment: А можно на примере?

Comment: @ikerya вот думаю вам поможет))

Comment: @ThusMod спасибо. Вы чуть-чуть запутались, но я поправил и мне помогло Ваше решение: http://pader.ru/share/d86hlw